# JavaScript Check Box

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Estou fazendo manutenção em um sistema, e encontrei o seguinte código:

```
$(".MinhaClass").die();
$(".MinhaClass").live('click', function () {
    // Código
}
```

`.MinhaClass` se refere a uma lista de `checkbox`. Fui incumbido de acrescentar no início da lista um `checkbox` para selecionar **Todos** os itens da lista. Logo pensei em fazer:

```
$("#selecionar-todos").change(function () {
      $('#lista input:checkbox').each(function () {
           $(this).click();
      });
});
```

Logo o sistema iria se comportar da mesma maneira de antes, sem muitas alterações.
Ao clicar em selecionar todos, todos os itens da lista são checados, inclusive o próprio checkbox "Selecionar Todos", mas ao clicar em um item individualmente, este é desmarcado e o checkbox "Selecionar Todos" também deve ser desmarcado.

Para isso, seria necessário identificar no primeiro código de onde vem a ação do click, se foi chamado pelo método que criei ou se foi acionado pelo click do mouse individualmente.
Tenho esse [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rz7fg338/2/) pra explicar melhor.

> Nota: O problema é que o checkbox Selecionar Todos só deve estar
>   marcado quando todas os itens estiverem marcados, caso algum seja
>   desmarcado, o checkbox selecionar todos também deve ser desmarcado...

Comment: Não faz muito sentido quando clicado em um individualmente desmarcar o restante uma vez que já tenha sido clicado em todos, image se fosse uma lista imensa onde o usuário quisesse marca todos e depois desmarcar somente um... mas bom, como as regras do jogo não é nossa...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altere o código para

```js
$(function(){
  $("#selecionar-todos").change(function() {
    $("#lista input:checkbox").prop('checked', this.checked);
  });
  $("#lista input:checkbox").change(function() {
    if (!this.checked) { // se desmarcou, limpa "selecionar todos"
      $("#selecionar-todos").prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input id="selecionar-todos" type="checkbox"/>Selecionar Todos</label>
<div id="lista">
    <label><input name="itens" type="checkbox" value="1"/>Item1</label>
    <label><input name="itens" type="checkbox" value="2"/>Item2</label>
    <label><input name="itens" type="checkbox" value="3"/>Item3</label>
    <label><input name="itens" type="checkbox" value="4"/>Item4</label>
</div>
```

Para atribuir a marcação utilizei a propriedade nativa `checked` ao invés do evento `click` (que alterna a seleção), essa propriedade pode ser acessada com a função [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) ou diretamente se for um objeto nativo (como o `this.checked` do código)

Comment: atualizei a pergunta, na verdade o `selecionar-todos` não está dentro da `lista`. Falha minha...

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda @Sanção mas o problema é que o checkbox selecionar Todos só deve estar marcado quando todas os itens estiverem marcados, caso algum seja desmarcado, o checkbox selecionar todos também deve ser...

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues editei a pergunta adicionando mais um evento, deve ter resolvido agora

Comment: mais uma vez espetacular! Só que para checar cada item, preciso usar o evento já existente, como descrito no início da pergunta. Dê uma olhadinha no [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rz7fg338/2/)...

Comment: não há a necessidade de usar o evento existente. Apesar de os dois eventos manipularem os mesmos elementos não há conflito das ações.